# SQL: Restore a database that was not detached properly

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore

I had problems with my harddisk on my dev box, yet I was able to save my MDF and LDF files. 
Needless to say, they were not detached properly.

I tried `sp_attach_single_file_db` which broke down with the following error:

> SQL Server detected a logical
>   consistency-based I/O error: invalid
>   protection option. It occurred during
>   a read of page (0:0) in database ID 0
>   at offset 0000000000000000 in file
>   'FILENAME'.  Additional messages in
>   the SQL Server error log or system
>   event log may provide more detail.
>   This is a severe error condition that
>   threatens database integrity and must
>   be corrected immediately. Complete a
>   full database consistency check (DBCC
>   CHECKDB). This error can be caused by
>   many factors; for more information,
>   see SQL Server Books Online.

I also tried to create a new database with the same size, stop the service, and overwrite the new mdf with the old mdf. But after starting the server, the database is not suspected, when i look at its properties its status is "shutdown".

I use SQL 2k8.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you bring the database up in emergency mode?

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase
SET EMERGENCY
```

If you can then you can run a DBCC on the database and see just how bad the corruption is.

If the hard drive was that hosed, the database may to badly damaged to do anything with.

Comment: Found out that the file(name) was recovered  but the contents where all over the place. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you close this question, since it is no longer relevant?

Comment: Sure, I can close it.